# Regex to match any non-alphanumeric character but the minus

Tags: .net, regex

I need to clean up filenames. So I have this code:

```
//\W_ is any non-word character (not [^a-zA-Z0-9_]).
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\W_]+");
return regex.Replace(source, replacement);
```

This works fine, but now I don't want to remove the minus (-), so I changed the regex to this:

```
[\W_^-]+
```

But that does not work. What did I miss?

Comment: If you use the caret (`^`) in a character class anywhere other than the beginning, it loses its special meaning. And when you use it properly, it negates everything in the character class. Use [`[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+`](http://rubular.com/r/onJOpL9Fwk) instead.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I figured one could do something simple with the \W, but I guess not. If you add your comment as an answer, I can approve it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<strike>Try using this regular expression :</strike>

```
[^\w-]+
```

**Edit :**

Seems that the right regular expression is :

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```

Comment: I believe this is partially incorrect, because it does not match the underscore.

Comment: The \w is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: Correct, so when you negate `\w` you are also excluding the underscore.

Comment: Ah yes sorry my mistake, tought he does want to leave it

Answer (score 4):

Just inverting what you want and what you don't:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```

[RegexPal link for this.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9-%5D%2b&input=256%2akl3vsd-vw_eew/dvc%2bvwecv%7Cvw%5Cah%2544e%24)